# Суммирование двух строчек(str)/цифр(int) python через знак вводимый input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суммирование двух строчек(str) python через знак вводимый input

```
a=str(input('Введите 1 число: ')) #10
b=str(input('Введите 2 число: ')) #101
c=input('Введите знак действия a_b: ') #+
d=(a,c,b) #тут должно получиться 10+101
print(d) #10101
```

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы вводилось "число", затем второе "число", вводился знак(в данном примере +) и чтобы всё это сложилось)
Если скажете как сделать так с цифрами, буду благодарен <З

Comment: так  что вы хотите получить 10101 или 111 ?

Comment: Судя по примеру `+` - конкатенация. :). Что же тогда такое `-`?

Answer (score 0):

если вы все таки делаете калькулятор

```
import operator as op

d = {'+': op.add, '-': op.sub}

a = int(input('Введите 1 число: ')) #10
b = int(input('Введите 2 число: ')) #101
c = input('Введите знак действия a_b: ') #+

print(d[c](a,b)) #111
```

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется арифметическое действие, то:

```
a=int(input('Введите 1 число: '))
b=int(input('Введите 2 число: '))
c=str(input('Введите знак действия a_b: '))

def result(a, b, c):
    if c == "+":
       return a + b
    elif c == "-":
        return a - b
    elif c == "/":
        return a / b
    elif c == "*":
        return a * b

print(result(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. input() и так возвращает тип str
2. Достаточно использовать F-строки
3. "Суммирование двух строчек" называеться конкатенацией

```
a = input('Введите 1 число: ') #10
b = input('Введите 2 число: ') #101
c = input('Введите знак действия a_b: ') #+
d = f"{a}{c}{b}"
print(d)
```

С цифрами тоже будет работать.